# Something redirects from HTTPS to HTTP and it is NOT our IIS server

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite

I need to "move" a company site from HTTP to HTTPS on IIS 7.5. I added the HTTPS Binding in IIS. However, any time I try to browse the site with "https://www.example.com" I am being redirected to "http://www.example.com/default.asp".

The problem is that I cannot find where this redirect/rewrite is defined, it is neither in web.config or applicationhost.config.

Where else can this redirect be defined?
Is there a way for me to check somehow what is responsible for this redirect? I have full permissions on the IIS server machine.

Comment: Your web application itself is most likely making this redirect. Check its settings or source code.

Comment: You are right! It was inside the ASP code.
I just found it out myself, came back to the site to delete my question and saw your comment.
If you want to post it as a reply, I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web application itself is most likely making this redirect. Check its settings or source code.

Comment: You were right.